# maximum subarray iii (from lintcode) dynamic programming solution

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, arrays

Can anyone walk me through this solution below? What does p mean? why its range j-1 to i? Thanks
Given an array of integers and a number k, find k non-overlapping subarrays which have the largest sum.

The number in each subarray should be contiguous.

Return the largest sum.

according to this blog(http://www.cnblogs.com/lishiblog/p/4183917.html), the DP analysis is

DP. d[i][j] means the maximum sum we can get by selecting j subarrays from the first i elements.

d[i][j] = max{d[p][j-1]+maxSubArray(p+1,i)}

we iterate p from i-1 to j-1, so we can record the max subarray we get at current p, this value can be used to calculate the max subarray from p-1 to i when p becomes p-1.

```
public class Solution {
/**
 * @param nums: A list of integers
 * @param k: An integer denote to find k non-overlapping subarrays
 * @return: An integer denote the sum of max k non-overlapping subarrays
 */
public int maxSubArray(ArrayList<Integer> nums, int k) {
    if (nums.size()<k) return 0;
    int len = nums.size();
    //d[i][j]: select j subarrays from the first i elements, the max sum we can get.
    int[][] d = new int[len+1][k+1];
    for (int i=0;i<=len;i++) d[i][0] = 0;        

    for (int j=1;j<=k;j++)
        for (int i=j;i<=len;i++){
            d[i][j] = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            //Initial value of endMax and max should be taken care very very carefully.
            int endMax = 0;
            int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;                
            for (int p=i-1;p>=j-1;p--){
                endMax = Math.max(nums.get(p), endMax+nums.get(p));
                max = Math.max(endMax,max);
                if (d[i][j]<d[p][j-1]+max)
                    d[i][j] = d[p][j-1]+max;                    
            }
        }

    return d[len][k];


}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does p mean: just a iterator. (Chinese Algorithm Coder always like short name for variable...)

Why its range j-1 to i:

Indeed, dp analysis should be:

d[i][j] = max{d[p][j-1]+maxSubArray(p+1,i)}  **j-1 <= p <= i-1**

Why must **p >= j-1**? Because as dp[i][j] define:

d[i][j] means the maximum sum we can get by selecting j subarrays from the first i elements.

You know , we can't select j sub-array without **non-overlapping** from j-1 elements. That is to say, dp[i][j] make sense when i >= j.

Any question, leave a comment here.

Comment: Thank you so much, Sayakiss;-) Now I understand the range for p. I am still confused at what endMax and max stands for. Also, why we get: d[i][j] = max{d[p][j-1]+maxSubArray(p+1,i)} with p's range as j-1 to i-1. So d[i][j] means max sum by selecting j subarray from first i elements, so d[p][j-1]means max sum by selecting j-1 subarray from first p element, then why we need to add maxSubArray(p+1, i)? In fact, I am confused at maxSubArray(p+1,i), does it mean from this Array[p+1...to len], find i non-overlapping subarray? Thanks;-)

Comment: `max` and `endMax` is about another question: How to find just one max subarray in O(n) Time? So do you have any idea about that? I think it's good try it yourself...

Comment: oh~I suddenly realize why I am stuck! Thanks @Sayakiss

Comment: @YuanVivienWang Welcome. You think it out by yourself, congratulations!

Comment: @ Sayakiss, not without your kind help;-) Thanks again!~